# How to fix my code so its returning num(digit) in my function?

Tags: javascript

```
function getDigit(number, index){
    let str = number.toString();
    let num;
    if (index === 0){
      index = str.length-1;
      num = str.charAt(index);

    }else{
      index = -(index);
      num = str.charAt(index);
    }
    return num;

  }
    console.log(getDigit(12345,3));
```

Hi!I'm trying to implement helper function getDigit() which will 
        return digit of the number which I pass to the function so e.g 
        getDigit(12345,1) should give me 4 as an output, and (12345,2) 
        should give me 3 as an output... Why my function doesn't return 
        anything??

Comment: Cause `str.charAt(-3)` is `undefined` ? What is `index = -(index);` supposed to do?

Comment: It supposed to give me (-index) ,so when i pass to my function index=3 i want to get index of -3.

Comment: Are you trying to do index -=1?

Comment: You cannot pass negative indexes to `charAt` to get characters from the end of the string. That's not how the function works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that works with negative indices or indices potentially bigger than the length of the string. The indices are wrapped around as if the string repeated indefinitely.

```js
function getDigit(number, index) {
  const str = (number || 0).toString().split('').reverse().join('');
  let idx = index;
  while (idx < 0) idx += str.length;
  return str.charAt(idx % str.length);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(
  [-10, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10].map(i => getDigit(12345, i))
));
```

Comment: Use `Math.abs()` instead of the ternary?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't allow negative indexes to mean count from the end.

If you want to convert the index to be from the end, subtract it from the length and then subtract 1. There's no need to treat `0` specially.

```js
function getDigit(number, index) {
  let str = number.toString();
  index = str.length - index - 1;
  let num = str.charAt(index);

  return num;

}
console.log(getDigit(12345, 3));
console.log(getDigit(12345, 0));
console.log(getDigit(12345, 1));
```